# Errors connecting to Vite Server

Tags: reactjs, vite

My project consists of a single-page React application coupled with a Vite backend server.  Frontend data will be received from an external API, and I will integrate it with the backend. My test routes keep returning "RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000." messages when I test endpoint functionality. The Vite server is run by running "npm run dev".  My attempts to change the URL from localhost to 127.0.0.1 and the PORT number have not resulted in successful connections. Below I have included the output from npm run dev, my server.js script, and my get request.

```
**Get Request**
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users

server.js
import express from "express";
import ViteExpress from "vite-express";
import cors from "cors";
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("client"));
app.use(cors());

const { Pool } = require("pg");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL });

pool.connect();

app.get("/api/users", (req, res) => {
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM users").then((result) => {
    res.send(result.rows);
  });
});
ViteExpress.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Express is listening on localhost:${port}`);
});

ViteExpress.bind(app, server);

**terminal output**
npm run dev

> vite-project@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.3.4  ready in 2809 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

**package.json**
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-mix": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding catch block to your requests

Comment: Although I appreciate your input, adding the catch did not work.